# adding div by clicking a button with js doesnt work in conjunction with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, database

Javascript code doesn't work in once I add PHP

I have a javascript function, which adds divs by clicking a button, the code works perfectly without PHP, but as soon as put in the following PHP code, it doesn't work anymore. Please help, thanks!

```
<script>$(document).ready(function(){
var i=1;
$('#add').click(function(){
    i++;
$('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td>Kategorie<br><select>"<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){echo '<option name="Kategoriename">' .$row['Kategorienname']. "</option>"; }?>"</select></td></select></td><td>Name<input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td>Inhalt<input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td>Preis<input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td>normal<input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Ø" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td>Preis<input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td>mittel<input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Ø" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td>Preis<input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td>groß<input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Ø" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td>Preis<input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td>Allergene<br><input type="checkbox" name="leer" value="leer"><img style="height:20px; width:20px;" src="../AuswahlIcon/allergene/a.png"><input type="checkbox" name="leer" value="leer"><img style="height:20px; width:20px;" src="../AuswahlIcon/allergene/b.png"><input type="checkbox" name="leer" value="leer"><img style="height:20px; width:20px;" src="../AuswahlIcon/allergene/c.png"><input type="checkbox" name="leer" value="leer"><img style="height:20px; width:20px;" src="../AuswahlIcon/allergene/d.png"><input type="checkbox" name="leer" value="leer"><img style="height:20px; width:20px;" src="../AuswahlIcon/allergene/e.png"><input type="checkbox" name="leer" value="leer"><img style="height:20px; width:20px;" src="../AuswahlIcon/allergene/f.png"><input type="checkbox" name="leer" value="leer"><img style="height:20px; width:20px;" src="../AuswahlIcon/allergene/g.png"><input type="checkbox" name="leer" value="leer"><img style="height:20px; width:20px;" src="../AuswahlIcon/allergene/h.png"><input type="checkbox" name="leer" value="leer"><img style="height:20px; width:20px;" src="../AuswahlIcon/allergene/l.png"><input type="checkbox" name="leer" value="leer"><img style="height:20px; width:20px;" src="../AuswahlIcon/allergene/m.png"><input type="checkbox" name="leer" value="leer"><img style="height:20px; width:20px;" src="../AuswahlIcon/allergene/n.png"><input type="checkbox" name="leer" value="leer"><img style="height:20px; width:20px;" src="../AuswahlIcon/allergene/o.png"><input type="checkbox" name="leer" value="leer"><img style="height:20px; width:20px;" src="../AuswahlIcon/allergene/p.png"><input type="checkbox" name="leer" value="leer"><img style="height:20px; width:20px;" src="../AuswahlIcon/allergene/r.png"></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
});

$(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){
    var button_id = $(this).attr("id"); 
    $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
});

$('#submit').click(function(){      
    $.ajax({
        url:"name2.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:$('#add_name').serialize(),
        success:function(data)
        {
            alert(data);
            $('#add_name')[0].reset();
        }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: what does it mean `put this code into my Database PHP code`? I see only js code here

Comment: Don't put PHP/MySQL inside JS like that, you're defeating its purpose. Plus, how are you accessing this as, an HTTP protocol or as `file:///` directly into your browser?

Comment: Lunin Roman, i request this code <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){echo '<option name="Kategoriename">' .$row['Kategorienname']. "</option>"; }?>" from my database

Answer (score 0):

This looks OK except that you are running PHP inside double quotes. In my experience this  doesn't work. Extend your PHP tags.

**From:**

```
$('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td>Kategorie<br><select>"<?php while
```

**To something similar to:**

```
$('#dynamic_field').append(<?php echo "<tr id=\"row'+i+'\"><td>Kategorie<br><select>"; while...
```

Comment: I did it step by step you are gonna say me but it doesn't work

Comment: Your comment is incoherent.